# Fine tune other layer beside last one for the inception v3 pretrained model using tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning

In my classification task, I have to fine tune the inception V3 pretrained model. However, when I search over internet, it seems like I can only fine tune the last layer of this model. I want to fine tune all layers or at least the fully connected layer not only the top one. Is there anybody has the solution for that?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Using any existing inception training code, telling it to load from a checkpoint containing the initial value you want to use, and running the normal training procedure will let you fine tune all layers.